# Add side bar menu in media uploader wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

hi i am running in one problem i have made custom media upload using js code and "wp.media"  api but problem is it's not displaying sidebar('Insert from gallery','set featured image') menu which is displaying when we add any image to post from backed

here is my code to open media upload popup ignore 'insertAtCaret' function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var file_frame;

    jQuery('#uploadmedia').live('click', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
        if (file_frame) {
            file_frame.open();
            return;
        }

        // Create the media frame.
        file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: jQuery(this).data('uploader_title'),
            button: {
                text: jQuery(this).data('uploader_button_text'),
            },
            multiple: false // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
        });

        // When an image is selected, run a callback.
        file_frame.on('select', function () {
            // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
            attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
        });

        // Finally, open the modal
        file_frame.open();

        file_frame.on('select', function () {

            var selection = file_frame.state().get('selection');

            selection.map(function (attachment) {

                attachment = attachment.toJSON();
                console.log(attachment.url);
                // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
                // $('#mycustomeditor').insertAtCaret('<img src="'+attachment.url+'" alt="" />');
            });
        });
    });
    $.fn.insertAtCaret = function (text) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (document.selection && this.tagName == 'TEXTAREA') {
                //IE textarea support
                this.focus();
                sel = document.selection.createRange();
                sel.text = text;
                this.focus();
            } else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
                //MOZILLA/NETSCAPE support
                startPos = this.selectionStart;
                endPos = this.selectionEnd;
                scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
                this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos) + text + this.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);
                this.focus();
                this.selectionStart = startPos + text.length;
                this.selectionEnd = startPos + text.length;
                this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
            } else {
                // IE input[type=text] and other browsers
                this.value += text;
                this.focus();
                this.value = this.value; // forces cursor to end
            }
        });
    };
});
```

here is what i get from above code[image: Currently displaying like this]

But i want to display Something like below

[image: I want to display something like that]

Thanks for your all response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off posting this question in the Stack Overflow Wordpress development forum:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/